# DIfference between Application and Integration service in IIB

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

Could anyone please explain the difference between application and integration service in IIB. I have referred through documentation but it was not clear. For example, if I have to create a service based on wsdl which has some 3 operations.Should I create it as integration service or application.Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with an Application it's roll your own in that you have to build everything.

With an Integration Service you can import a WSDL and the framework of your flow will be generated for you.

So if you are being given WSDL's for the services you want to build then using an IS may be the way to go.

Personally I don't like some of the aspects of the generated code but that's me. I'm currently working on a project that uses REST API's and am using the REST API project option for my projects and it generates code.

Comment: Hi @TJA Thanks for response. Yes I need to create interfaces defined only in WSDL. So, one more question, can we group multiple integration services under single application.For example, if I have 3 WSDLs which have 3 operations each, I need to define 3 interfaces in a single project using 3 WSDLs, how can I achieve this? Can we group multiple integration services in a single project?

Comment: @Ramakrishna as they are separate services I'd actually keep them that way, you may be able to cobble something together but you would then be coupling them together from a change management point of view. I doubt an Integration Service will accept more than one WSDL you could drop three SoapInput nodes onto a MessageFlow but yet again why would you. At the end of the day keep things simple and separate. And independent

Comment: Thanks @TJA for the response. Understood.